# How to replace usage of static Entity::load method calls for better testability?

Tags: 8, testing

In my method that I'm testing in UnitTestCase based class I have a statement:

```
Term::load(self::HARDCODED_TID);
```

Any other way to load Term object to make it 'mockable'?

Comment: Use the term storage handler.

Comment: @Eyal could you provide an example of using TermStorage directly?

Comment: `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('term')->load(self::HARDCODED_TID);`

Comment: The storage class can be initiated with a container object so it can be easily mocked.

Comment: \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load(self::HARDCODED_TID);

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is (without changing legacy code):

```
   $entityManager = $this->getMockBuilder('\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManager')
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->getMock();

    $entityManager->expects($this->any())
      ->method('getEntityTypeFromClass')
      ->will($this->returnCallback(function ($class_name) {
        return $class_name == 'Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term' ? 'taxonomy_term' : '';
      }));

    $term = $this->getMockBuilder('Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term')
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->getMock();

    $termStorage = $this->getMockBuilder('\Drupal\taxonomy\TermStorage')
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->getMock();

    $termStorage->expects($this->any())
      ->method('load')
      ->willReturn($term);

    $this->termStorage = $termStorage;

    $entityManager->expects($this->any())
      ->method('getStorage')
      ->will($this->returnCallback(function ($type) {
        return $type == 'taxonomy_term' ? $this->termStorage : NULL;
      }));

    $this->container = new ContainerBuilder();
    $this->container->set('entity.manager', $entityManager);
    \Drupal::setContainer($this->container);
```